# Ocean modifier source code

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation

**Is source code for the ocean modifier accessible?** I looked through my Blender installation, but I can't find it.

I'm trying to create a game (not in Blender because it's for iOS/Android) and would like to use real-time generated ocean waves rather than using prebaked .obj files, but have no idea how to make waves like that on my own.

Answer (score 4):

You can't find the source within the Blender installation because it's compiled code (C/C++).

An probably older implementation: [Blender_Ocean.c](http://wiki.blender.org/uploads/c/c6/Blender_Ocean.c) has pointers to the original paper by Jerry Tessendorf [Simulating Ocean Water](http://graphics.ucsd.edu/courses/rendering/2005/jdewall/tessendorf.pdf).

You find the current source file in [GIT](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/ocean.c) version control

Answer (score 0):

From [Blender's wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Simulate/Ocean#History):

> The core simulator was developed by Drew Whitehouse, for the Houdini
>   Ocean Toolkit. This was ported to C by Hamed Zaghaghi and integrated
>   in a patch for the Blender 2.4 series, sponsored by ProMotion
>   Studios/Red Cartel during production of the short film Lighthouse.
>
> In this work, Matt Ebb re-integrated the core simulator for Blender
>   2.5, and added additional functionality, fixes, and optimisations, sponsored by the 'Save the Ocean Sim' project.

So perhaps the [Houdini Ocean Toolkit](https://github.com/eloop/hot) is a good place to start for a non-Blender implementation.